# Windows cmd suggested input

Tags: windows, input, cmd

I am attempting to write a .bat file that prompts the user for a file path before continuing. However, this is a script that I plan on running repeatedly on the same file, so it would save me a lot of time to not have to re-enter that path every time. I plan on saving the path to another file each time it's run. What I'm hoping i can do then is, when the prompt comes up, have the previous path pre-entered. That way I could either just hit enter, or backspace and change it to a new path. How would I go about pre-entering the text? Is it possible? Any feedback or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
IF EXIST %~dpn0.save.cmd (CALL %~dpn0.save.cmd)
SET /p "savedpath=Please specify file path or press Enter for default [%savedpath%] : "
ECHO SET savedpath=%savedpath%> %~dpn0.save.cmd
```

The beauty of this approach is that, if elsewhere in the script you decide that the preserved value should be forgotten, you just delete the .save.cmd file.

Years ago - when I used to work in command scripts everyday - we had examples where these types of values would come from a different section of the same script file, and the preserved values would simply be written back to the same file; however, I can't recall the details, and this separate-file approach will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("c:\path to\wherever\your\file.is") do set "filepath=%%a"
set /p "filepath=Select path or just [Enter] for %filepath%"
echo select path was "%filepath%"
>"c:\path to\wherever\your\file.is" echo %filepath%
```

The point is that `set /p` leaves the target variable unmolested if the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key alone is used.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try this out when i get a chance. I'm sort of new to cmd, so I don't entirely understand all of what you said, but I'll do some research.